# Delphi ITask - should I free it after completed?

Tags: delphi, parallel-processing

I create an `ITask` (`TTask.Create(...)`). It works as expected. After it finishes the job, the task status shows me "completed".

Should I free the `ITask` object somehow, or it is freed automatically?

Comment: In general, you don't free interfaces. They are reference counted.

Comment: @Dsm, lifetime of the implementor instance depends on them. One can still implement interface e.g. in a plain `TObject` class descendant. But I would agree with you, in general, interfaces are implemented by `TInterfacedObject` descendants if you meant that freeing.

Comment: @Victoria, yes I know, hence 'in general', but one of the main reasons for using interfaces is to avoid the need for freeing an object and the OP here is using an ITask rather than a TTask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As with any interface that implements `TInterfacedObject` in their descendants (default), `ITask` is reference counted. This means that it will self-destruct, once its reference count is zero. This means that you don't have to free it manually.

See [Memory Management of Interface Objects](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Memory_Management_of_Interface_Objects):

> One of the concepts behind the design of interfaces is ensuring the lifetime management of the objects that implement them. The _AddRef and _Release methods of IInterface provide a way to implement this lifetime management. _AddRef and _Release track the lifetime of an object by incrementing the reference count on the object when an interface reference is passed to a client, and will destroy the object when that reference count is zero.

---

If the task is finished, it is also possible to destroy `FTask` by assigning a nil value. That will also decrement the reference count.

Comment: I'm a bit newbie to Delphi. I understand your answer, but I have one more question: BEFORE creating the ITask object (FTask :=TTask.Create(...), the FTask variable is nil (or it is not assigned). AFTER the FTask finished the job, I can still reach this object (e.g: I can read the FTask.Status). This means for me, that the object is not destructed. What I'm missing?

Comment: It's called a "dangling pointer". A variable can point to memory that has been freed. As soon as that memory is (re)used for something else, you'll most likely incur an access violation if you attempt to use the pointer. Delphi does not clear references to freed memory - it's your job to ensure that you don't access memory that has been freed.

Comment: If you still have `FTask` in scope, it is not destroyed yet. Once it goes out of scope, the ref count will be decremented and the object will be destroyed. (Unless you have taken another reference on `FTask` that outlives its scope)

Comment: @HeartWare, no that is not it. See my comment above.

Comment: I take issue with the first paragraph. Many interface implementations don't self destruct.

Comment: @HeartWare: Could you please elaborate? As far as I recall, Interface references are either `nil` or they point to a valid instance. There are no dangling pointers. Of course, this only applies as long as normal reference counting is taking place and you do not use (weird) implementations like Mr. Heffernan mentions.

Comment: @Gabor: You are not missing anything. You can still reach it, therefore it is not destroyed yet. If you assign a new task to your `FTask` field and the task is not running anymore, the `TTask` object will get destroyed.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I updated the answer. Interfaces that bypasses the ref counting mechanism is for special purposes. Creating singleton objects that are forced to outlive its scope is one example. See [System.Generics.Defaults.TSingletonImplementation](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Generics.Defaults.TSingletonImplementation).

Comment: LURD, @GünthertheBeautiful, My comment was a general observation and not for Interfaces explicitly. You are both correct that for interfaces, it is generally not possible to have dangling pointers.